# fancy box not open in single click,require double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, shopify

Hi i want to open a certain div in fancybox
i did like this

```
<script>
$('a#img_main_squre').click(function(e){        
  $.fancybox(this,{
    href: '#first_lightbox', 
    modal: true
   });
      e.preventDefault();   
});

</script>

<div style="display:none">
 <div id = "first_lightbox">  
   <div id = "lightbox_image">
     <img src="{{ settings.content_module_img1 | img_url: "medium" }}" />
   </div>
   <div id= "lightbox_content">        

     <img src="{{ settings.content_module_image1_logo | img_url: "small" }}" />
     <span>{{ settings.first_headline }}</span>
     <span>{{ settings.second_headline }}</span>         

   </div>  
 </div>
```

```
<div class="product-single__photo-wrapper" >
  <a href="first_lightbox" id="img_main_squre">
    <img src="{{ settings.content_module_img1 | img_url: "small" }}" />
  </a>  
</div>
```

I have tried almost all possible solution available on SO, but none of them is working
i am using jQuery 1.11.8
and fancybox -v 2.1.5

i want to display hidden div 'first_lightbox' in the fancybox while clicking #img_main_squre

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: some how jsfiddle not working but on my twing template its working on double click

Comment: @Anish you need to initialize it outside of click. Try my answer below.

Comment: @TechBreak page  redirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize it outside of `click`. Because on first `click` event it is getting initialized and on second `click` it working for you.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       //initialize outside click
       $('a#img_main_squre').fancybox({
          modal: true
       });
    });
</script>
```

As you are working on `modal` based mechanism you need to `target` the modal using convention of `#` like suggested and not required to put `href` in fancybox.

```
 <a href="#first_lightbox" id="img_main_squre">
```

Comment: instead of open in fancy box its redirect the page ,

Comment: This require double click to load fancy box

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function(){                       
                     $('a#img_main_squre').fancybox({
    modal: true
});  });
    
 $('a#img_main_squre').fancybox({
    modal: true
});
</script>  i have initialize twice outside click, and its working.Strange but its working how I do not know

Comment: you need to wrap your scripts in ready() to get going with jQuery. Does it solve your issue? I just focused on fancybox initialization considering all the jquery stuff was taken care. Glad if you moved ahead

Comment: No,I did it twice ones in ready function, and second outside it and then its working

Comment: @Anish remove outside initialization. It should work with ready() perfeectly.

Comment: it doesn't work if i remove any one of them, its strange but true

Comment: can you pls helpme coz close, and navigation button not shown up

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the inline example from documentation?

The link should be `<a href="#first_lightbox" id="img_main_squre">` (note the hash before the id in href attribute) and the javascript will be just this:

```
$('a#img_main_squre').fancybox({
    modal: true
});
```